# How does Excel's predictive autocomplete feature work?

Tags: windows, autocomplete, microsoft365, excel-2019

I'm entering dozens of names into a column in an Excel table and the predictive autocomplete usually figures out which name I'm typing after the second or third letter, if it's a unique enough name. Sometimes, however, what I would think is an obvious entry doesn't autocomplete until I've almost typed the entire string.

For example, I type "Self Referral" and don't get the full prediction until I type "Self Referr", then autocomplete provides the last two letters. There are no other strings in the column which are even close to this value so I don't know why it waits so long to complete. I notice this happens when I haven't typed that value in a while, and if it's been long enough the autocomplete never appears at all.

My question is how does autocomplete prediction work? Does Excel store a certain number of values in the column in a cache which removes older values as newer values appear?

Row 1 value: "Self Referral" (manually typed)
Rows 2 through n-1: Other values which don't start with the string "self"
Row n: I type "Self Referr" and then the rest of the word "referral" appears
Row n+1: I type "Se" and then the cell autocompletes with "Self Referral"

Using Excel desktop with Microsoft 365 subscription